# Laravel Schedule:list produces DateTimeZone error

Tags: laravel, scheduler, laravel-artisan

- Laravel Version: 8.78.1
- PHP Version: 8.0.10

**Description**

Whilst creating my first scheduled command, trying to list my schedules with

```
php artisan schedule:list
```

throws the error:

```
DateTime::setTimezone(): Argument #1 ($timezone) must be of type DateTimeZone, null given at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleListCommand.php:43
```

changing my command to

```
php artisan schedule:list --timezone=Europe/London
```

gives:

```
DateTime::setTimezone(): Argument #1 ($timezone) must be of type DateTimeZone, string given at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ScheduleListCommand.php:43
```

**Steps To Reproduce:**

My schedule:

```
$schedule->command('email:expired-licences')->weekdays()->at('08:00');
```

My custom command doesn't actually do anything yet.

Eventually I found a solution if I edited ScheduleListCommand.php
changing:

```
->setTimezone($this->option('timezone', config('app.timezone')))
```

to

```
->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($this->option('timezone', config('app.timezone'))))
```

but only if I use the --timezone=Europe/London switch (not sure if this is required), if not then the $this->option doesn't seem to be accepting the config('app.timezone') as a default.

Even:

```
$schedule->command('route:list')->weekdays()->at('08:00');
```

doesn't work on my system - not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in the `laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\ScheduleListCommand.php` and was fixed in the [v8.79.0 release](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.79.0)